# Программно отозвать разрешения в React native Expo

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo

Есть приложение на React native, Expo. Надо сделать в приложении настройку для запроса/отказа от разрешения на получение уведомлений. В [документации](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/permissions/) вижу метод для запроса разрешений, но вот метод отказа от разрешений не наблюдаю. Возможно ли программно отзывать разрешения или только через настройках приложения руками пользователь может это делать?

Answer (score 0):

Отзывать разрешения может только пользователь ручками в настройках. Зато можно в Expo можно, например, остановить eventListner и пуши перестанут выводиться на устройстве.